# Odd RPM behaviour, installed but not at the same time?

Tags: installation, java, redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

I'm having issues with Java on my RedHat virtual machine. So I went to Oracle's site to download the newest version of JRE and JDK. I got the RPM and did an `rpm -i` to install, but it tells me its already installed. I figure I would reinstall it just to be sure, so I `rpm -e` to remove and it tells me it isn't installed. What am I missing?

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# rpm -i jre-6u26-linux-i586.rpm 
        package jre-1.6.0_26-fcs.i586 is already installed
[root@localhost Desktop]# rpm -e jre-6u26-linux-i586
error: package jre-6u26-linux-i586.rpm is not installed
[root@localhost Desktop]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename doesn't necessarily reflect the package's actual name. Use `rpm -qp` on the file to figure out what the package is really named.

Comment: Yep, figured that out. +1 and accepted.

Comment: errr.... in 9 minutes that is.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it. The package name is different from the RPM file. Even if it doesn't seem that way with the verbose from the terminal.

```
rpm -e jre-1.6.0_26-fcs.i586
```